# Connect edges of array?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I created a shape out of a single mesh/edge.

[image]

I added an array modifier and a curve modifier to create the rough shape of a banana.

Is there a way to add a "skin" to the result in Blender 2.8 in a non-destructive way, e.g. by using a modifier or some other technique?

[Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmQg3eUYceo2om5V-8cyfMxFn8PG?e=gcuGg2)

Comment: You could apply both modifiers and in edit mode, manually create faces, but it will take a very long time. Alternatively, you can add a cylinder, add some edge loops and make a banana-like shape with proportional editing.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/138939#138939 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/lofting-between-two-different-shapes-along-a-path

Comment: That is a great collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extrude your cross section by a small amount on the Y axis, then adjust the "Merge distance" parameter of the Array Modifier :
[image]