# Morphing object along curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

is there a simple way to morph object along a bezier curve?
For example: a rope with one square end and one round end.

Example:
[image]

If it *can’t* be done, that is helpful too.
I’ll stop trying to find a way.

Thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142436/lofting-over-three-bezier-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/lofting-between-two-different-shapes-along-a-path

Comment: @batFINGER produced a nice script to help with one mechanism for this [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/lofting-can-i-copy-a-shape-keyed-mesh-for-each-frame-of-its-animation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve found the solution.

Notes:
1) There isn’t a direct way to morph along a curve
2) The result can be achieved with the *curve modifier*

My solution:
[image]

Big thanks to:
[Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) for pointing me in the right direction
[Patdog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/26911/patdog)
[Haunt_House](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1077/haunt-house)

Comment: How does it differs from Patdog's answer? Sorry I missed something ...

Comment: Oh, it doesn't :). This was my first post here, I didn't know about duplicates then (or Blender for that matter). I'll mark it as a dupe, thanks :).

Comment: Oh, this completely changed the value of this post !!! Welcome to the community (2019) and congratulation to the score 20k per year :)

Comment: :D Made my day, thanks