# Tube with variable section

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, extrude, bevel

I would like to create a tube which has a square input section, a circular output section and a smooth transition between the two.

I would like the tube to follow a curve, so I figured I could create a Bezier Curve and then use the Bevel object feature. However this is gives me a uniform cross section.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Related: [Morphing object along curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/154994/78972)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a (destructive) way to do it:

- Create a 8 vertex square, array it (*Constant Offset* mode) and make it follow a curve:

[image]

- Apply the modifiers, select each square and round it more and more with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (*To Sphere*) and playing with the *Operator* box factor:

[image]

- Switch to *Edge Select* mode, select all and right click > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

- In the Operator box, play with the *Number of Cuts* value:

[image]