# Create a surface between two curves

Tags: objects, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Hi, I want to create a surface between two curves. Please any one guide me

Thankyou

Comment: Do you need to keep them as curves, or is it ok to convert them to meshes?

Comment: I want to convert a mesh @InTheAbsenceOfFear

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-make-uv-loft-like-3ds-max-in-blender-using-curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/loft-tool-in-blender-2-8/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/746/lofting-between-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/lofting-between-two-different-shapes-along-a-path

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the curves you want to bridge with a surface are selected (your image tells me that they are). Then you need to join them into a single object. This is done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. The next step is to convert to mesh. Right click to pull up the *Object Context Menu*, and select *Convert to* -> *Mesh*.
[image: Object Context Menu]
Go into edit mode, and make sure everything is selected. If it isn't, press <kbd>A</kbd>. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the *Edge* menu, or access it by clicking *Edge* in the menu bar near the top, then select *Bridge Edge Loops*.
[image: Edge menu]
Your two curves should now be joined with a bridge of faces. I used two circles in my images, but the workflow is the same.
[image: Edge loops bridged]

As a side note, from the shape of your curves, I'm pretty sure you'll get self-intersections. This is rarely, if ever, a good idea. Such objects cannot exist in the real world, and even if you have a use case for self-intersections, beware that it may cause shading artifacts when rendering.

Comment: Thankyou so much...It is working fine

Comment: @Jenifer, if it has answered please mark the answer as good (check sign on the top left of the answer)